We need some work!
This is not a question, close it if you need to.
I would like to remind everyone that we really need to ask more questions every day.

We have no hope to get past beta if we continue like this.
Please ask as many questions as you can.
What ever comes to your mind, and you think it would be valuable for the community to see, ask it.
Don't be lazy.
A few more visits would be good.
If you have nothing to do, why not visit this site?
Thanks.

Meta is not only about questions but, you could improve by also adding suggestions. :P

Yes, what are your thoughts on how to try and engage more users?
